# xPath en tabla dinamica

Tags: javascript, test, xpath

Tengo la siguiente estructura, para testear en wdio, la idea es obtener el % del cpu en la pestaña de chrome, pero no logro obtener el % correcto ya que la tabla es dynamica, por lo que cambia de posicion el %;

```
<div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
        <span role="columnheader">Name</span>
        <span role="columnheader">Memory</span>
        <span role="columnheader">Disk</span>
        <span role="columnheader">CPU</span>
        <span role="columnheader">Network</span>
    </div>
    <div role="row">
        <span role="cell">Chrome</span>
        <span role="cell">41.7 MB</span>
        <span role="cell">0 MB/s</span>
        <span role="cell">6.6%</span>
        <span role="cell">3.2 Mbps</span>
    </div>
    <div role="row">
        <span role="cell">Edge</span>
        <span role="cell">22.7 MB</span>
        <span role="cell">4 MB/s</span>
        <span role="cell">5.6%</span>
        <span role="cell">4.2 Mbps</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

La idea es conseguir a travez de xPath los valores pero no he tenido exito, lo que consigo es obtener siempre la cabecera (CPU) y el navegador usado (Chrome), existe alguna manera de poner dos condicionantes de busqueda en el xpath?

Comment: Hasta ahora sólo has contesguido obtener la cabecera de Chrome. Pero por favor, muestra el código para que te podamos ayudar a depurarlo y conseguir lo que planteas en tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

No has explicado bien de qué manera puede cambiar el documento XML o HTML pero si quieres primero evaluar la posición de la celda de CPU y entonces utilizarla en otras expresiones, solo versions actuales de XPath, como 3.0 o 3.1 lo permiten en una sola expresión:

```
let 
  $rows := //div[@role = 'rowgroup']/div[@role = 'row'],
  $cpuCellPos := count($rows[1]/span[@role = 'columnheader'][. = 'CPU']/preceding-sibling::span[@role = 'columnheader']) + 1
return
  $rows[position() gt 1]/span[@role = 'cell'][$cpuCellPos]
```

Se puede utilizar XPath 3.1 con JavaScript con la ayuda de SaxonJS (https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html):

```js
const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`let 
  $rows := //div[@role = 'rowgroup']/div[@role = 'row'],
  $cpuCellPos := count($rows[1]/span[@role = 'columnheader'][. = 'CPU']/preceding-sibling::span[@role = 'columnheader']) + 1
return
  $rows[position() gt 1]/span[@role = 'cell'][$cpuCellPos]`,
  document,
  { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' }
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>


<div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
        <span role="columnheader">Name</span>
        <span role="columnheader">Memory</span>
        <span role="columnheader">Disk</span>
        <span role="columnheader">CPU</span>
        <span role="columnheader">Network</span>
    </div>
    <div role="row">
        <span role="cell">Chrome</span>
        <span role="cell">41.7 MB</span>
        <span role="cell">0 MB/s</span>
        <span role="cell">6.6%</span>
        <span role="cell">3.2 Mbps</span>
    </div>
    <div role="row">
        <span role="cell">Edge</span>
        <span role="cell">22.7 MB</span>
        <span role="cell">4 MB/s</span>
        <span role="cell">5.6%</span>
        <span role="cell">4.2 Mbps</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto te daría los elementos `span` con los valores, pero es fácil extraer dirctamente a los valores también:

```js
const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`let 
  $rows := //div[@role = 'rowgroup']/div[@role = 'row'],
  $cpuCellPos := count($rows[1]/span[@role = 'columnheader'][. = 'CPU']/preceding-sibling::span[@role = 'columnheader']) + 1
return
  $rows[position() gt 1]/span[@role = 'cell'][$cpuCellPos]/string()`,
  document,
  { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' }
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>


<div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
        <span role="columnheader">Name</span>
        <span role="columnheader">Memory</span>
        <span role="columnheader">Disk</span>
        <span role="columnheader">CPU</span>
        <span role="columnheader">Network</span>
    </div>
    <div role="row">
        <span role="cell">Chrome</span>
        <span role="cell">41.7 MB</span>
        <span role="cell">0 MB/s</span>
        <span role="cell">6.6%</span>
        <span role="cell">3.2 Mbps</span>
    </div>
    <div role="row">
        <span role="cell">Edge</span>
        <span role="cell">22.7 MB</span>
        <span role="cell">4 MB/s</span>
        <span role="cell">5.6%</span>
        <span role="cell">4.2 Mbps</span>
    </div>
</div>
```